# Security: Is it a good practice to name folders on the server that are difficult to guess?

Tags: linux, apache, security, directory, web-folders

Security question: Is it a good practice to name folders on the server by names that are difficult to guess (8+ symbols, not a simple "admin" or "services")? I'm asking about folders that contain not just icons or .js files or .css files, but .php files and are protected by .htaccess file (deny from all).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Security through obscurity isn't.

Plus it's really irritating for anybody using the machine via a shell, ftp, etc.

What would it protect against? Regardless of names, folder access should be handled by the machine's and/or network's normal security mechanisms. If they get past that, it doesn't matter what your artifacts are named–Ur PwNeD.

Comment: +1 for explaining *how* security through obscurity doesn't help.

Answer (score 3):

Good practice would be to keep your PHP files outside your web server's document root. E.g., if your doc root is /var/www, then you might have there just a single index.php file, and all that file does is launch your app:

```
set_include_path('/something/besides/var/www');
require_once 'foo.php';
require_once 'bar.php';
do_something();
```

This way, your web server doesn't even know that the PHP files exist, and can't serve them even if you have an accidentally misconfigured .htaccess.

Answer (score 2):

This is [security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).  While there is no harm in doing it , It doesn't give **anything** in terms of security.